# Parse URL parameter and create a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to have the URL parameters as a "real" dict. How can I achieve that? I don't want to use `params.split()` multiple times.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url = 'http://nohost.com?params=depth:1,width:500,size:small'

the_url = urlparse(url)
url_part, params = the_url.path, the_url.query

print(params)  # params=depth:1,width:500,size:small
```

At the end of the day I want to have a real dictionary from the URL parameters

```
params = {'depth': 1, 'width': 500, 'size': 'small'}
```

Comment: You can [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to get `{'params': ['depth:1,width:500,size:small']}`, but beyond that you'd need to DIY.

Comment: You do realize, that by the existing definition of how a query string is structured, you have only _one_ URL parameter here, right? The full `depth:1,width:500,size:small` part, is that one parameter's value. So you _will_ have to parse that yourself, unless for some reason a parser for this non-standard format would already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the params yourselves. As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, you can choose to use parse_qs to get a dict of list after parsing the output of urlparse and then pretty much implement the parsing logic.

Something like this,

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = 'http://nohost.com?params=depth:1,width:500,size:small'

url_parts = urlparse(url)
parsed_str = parse_qs(url_parts.query)['params'][0]

params_dict = {
    key: int(value) if value.isdigit() else value
    for key, value in (pair.split(':') for pair in parsed_str.split(','))
}


print(params_dict) # {'depth': 1, 'width': 500, 'size': 'small'}
```

Comment: Thx..This solution is perfect for me